# codeigniter active record Join multiple select statements

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, join

I cannot find any refrence on joining multiple selects like the query below in active record, anyone know how such is done?

```
select a1.act, a1.date, a2.clos
from
(
SELECT count( AccountActiveDate ) act, DATE_FORMAT( AccountActiveDate, '%Y-%m' ) date
FROM customert cust
GROUP BY YEAR( AccountActiveDate ) , MONTH( AccountActiveDate ) 
) a1
join
(
SELECT  count( AccountClosedDate ) clos,  DATE_FORMAT( AccountClosedDate, '%Y-%m' ) date
FROM customert cust2
GROUP BY YEAR( AccountClosedDate) , MONTH( AccountClosedDate) 
) a2
ON a1.date = a2.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put you sql string like this:

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE')
```

Example:

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE age > 18');
```